# PNG images are not rendered when uploaded to Heroku nodeJS app

Tags: node.js, heroku, png, angular-fullstack

I created a small app out of Angular-fullstack which works locally and shows all the images. When app is uploaded to Heroku, png images are not rendered and I can see that all images are exists on the server but somehow images got damage

Link to the app:
http://afternoon-shelf-4757.herokuapp.com/

Comment: without seeing the code it would be hard to help you

Comment: Please also post a sample "damaged" PNG.  Without seeing one I'm guessing that they begin with a CgBI chunk and are therefore not valid PNG files.

Answer (score 0):

You could tell git that your png files are binary and should not be modified.

Add this line to your .gitattributes file:

`*.png binary`

For more info see [Git-Attributes Binary Files](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Binary-Files)